# Why do we use pointers for glfwCreateWindow? - OpenGL

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm currently learning OpenGL, I'm also fairly new to C++. My question that I have is why is a pointer used here.

```cpp
GLFWwindow *mainWindow = glfwCreateWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Test Window", NULL, NULL);
```

I get what pointers are, just not why they are used here. All answers are appreciated, thanks.

Comment: "Why do we use pointers when declaring a variable with a value that is a function". The value is not a function. That would be a function pointer. Here you CALL a function that returns a pointer to a window handle structure. Since the function returns a struct, it has to be stored somewhere. The chosen approach here is to create the structure somewhere (on the heap) and return a pointer to it.

Comment: @DrPhil So it returns a C++ structure, which we need a pointer to because we can't really have a variable store a structure. With the pointer we can then axis everything we need. Is that correct? P.S. nice name

Comment: _I understand exactly what the code does._ No, you don't.

Comment: @ThomasSablik good point :)

Comment: "we can't really have a variable store a structure."  - we can (e.g. a `std::string`) but the designers of this interface decided to go with pointers

Comment: You can return a copy of an object in a function and store it in a variable. But in this case you don't want a copy of a window handle. You want a reference (pointer) to specific window handle.

Comment: @ThomasSablik Thanks, that is a great explanation!

Comment: Note that while the handle is probably sitting on the heap, don't try to `delete` it yourself. Call `glfwDestroyWindow` to dispose of it when you are done. It might not have been `new`ed and Crom only know what other book-keeping lurks in the back-end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no inherent necessity for a `glfwCreateWindow()` to return a pointer-to-a window, rather than an actual window. The OpenGL library could possibly have been designed so that that code would look different, e.g.:

```
GLFWwindow mainWindow = glfwCreateWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Test Window", nullptr, nullptr);
```

or in fact, just using a construction of a `GLFWindow`:

```
GLFWwindow mainWindow { WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Test Window", nullptr, nullptr };
```

still, there are several possible reasons why the API was designed this way:

1. Until C++ 2017, compilers were not required to perform [RVO - return value optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12953127/1593077). That meant that if your function returns a value of type `T`, you could theoretically need to copy the `T` you create within the function to the destination location at the code which called the function. In your case - returning a `GLFWwindow` might have required making a *copy* of the `GLFWwindow`; and that could possibly have been problematic for the library (I don't know OpenGL so I have no idea).
2. When your function returns a `T*`, the pointed-to object can be anything that "is a T" - which means any type that inherits from `T` (!); while if you return a plain `T` - you can't return inheriting types. So if there is a class hierarchy of `GLFWwindow`s, all inheriting from `GLFWwindow` as a base class - it can make sense to to return a pointer to that base class, for you to handle generically.

---

<sub>PS - Having five constructor parameters, and passing arguments which make it rather unclear what constructor parameter is being set, is problematic design. Specifically - we can't tell what the first `nullptr` signifies, nor how it differs from the second `nullptr`.</sub>

Answer (score -1):

1. You need a reference to the window directly to make changes to it.
2. If it returns a C++ structure and the definition of the structure is like :

```
    struct someStructure{
        int width;
        int length;
        string name;
        //some more variables
    }
```

then at the time of passing this structure to any function/method - you will be passing 

[ **sizeof(int) + sizeof(int) + sizeof(string) +...+ sizeof(int)**] **bytes of data - which is say 64 bytes** *(which can also increase with time as you modify/alter your structure*.

But if you pass the pointer reference instead, it only sends an address (8bit/16bit/32bit etc.. ) which would depend on your system addressing scheme, it will be fixed and won't change even if you add more members to your structure in future.